# Question of call function in cmd batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, goto

I have a question about the call function of cmd batch file.

According to the source code below:

If you I want to call a REDO/NORMAL function, when the function end, the question is it possible return to **ECHO Copying File...** to run and until to **EXIT(0)** to the end?

Thanks.

**Source Code**

```
@ECHO OFF

ECHO Checking Network Connection...
ECHO.
TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL

PING -n 2 192.168.1.1 | FIND "TTL" > NUL 
    
IF errorlevel 1 (
    
    Powershell -noP -c "Write-Host 'ERROR: Failure! Please Check Network Connection! Script Exit!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor RED"
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    TIMEOUT /T 5
    EXIT(0)
    
) ELSE (
    
    Powershell -noP -c "Write-Host 'INFO: Success! Network Connected!' -ForegroundColor GREEN"
    TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK > NUL 

)


FOR /F %%a IN ('Powershell -Nop -c "Get-Date -Format 'HH:mm'"') DO SET time=%%a

IF %time% GTR 12:00 (

GOTO REDO
    
) ELSE (

GOTO NORMAL

)

ECHO Copying File...
ECHO.
    
TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    
COPY "C:\temp\A.csv" "D:\temp\"

ECHO.
ECHO Copy Completed!
TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    
EXIT(0)

:REDO
ECHO THIS IS REDO FUNCTION

:NORMAL
ECHO THIS IS NORMAL FUNCTION
```

Comment: Are you looking for the [call](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) command?

Comment: GOTO not equal to CALL? Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: no, they are not equal. `GOTO` doesn't save a return point, `call` does. See `goto /?` and `call /?` (or look them up in SS64). Btw: the correct syntax for `exit` is `exit 0` (no parentheses). But you shouldn't use that either, because it exits your script. Use `goto :eof` (`:eof` is a built-in label and means **E**nd **O**f **F**ile) or `exit /b 0` (see `exit /?`)

Comment: You will need to terminate your `:REDO` section by `goto :EOF` or `exit /B` in order not to unintentionally fall into the `:NORMAL` section…

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    @ECHO OFF

ECHO Checking Network Connection...
ECHO.
TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL

PING -n 2 192.168.1.1 | FIND "TTL" > NUL 
    
IF errorlevel 1 (
    
    Powershell -noP -c "Write-Host 'ERROR: Failure! Please Check Network Connection! Script Exit!' -BackgroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor RED"
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    TIMEOUT /T 5
    EXIT(0)
    
) ELSE (
    
    Powershell -noP -c "Write-Host 'INFO: Success! Network Connected!' -ForegroundColor GREEN"
    TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK > NUL 

)


FOR /F %%a IN ('Powershell -Nop -c "Get-Date -Format 'HH:mm'"') DO SET time=%%a

IF %time% GTR 12:00 (

GOTO REDO
:BACK
) ELSE (

GOTO NORMAL
:BACK
)

ECHO Copying File...
ECHO.
    
TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    
COPY "C:\temp\A.csv" "D:\temp\"

ECHO.
ECHO Copy Completed!
TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    
EXIT(0)

:REDO
ECHO THIS IS REDO FUNCTION
GOTO BACK

:NORMAL
ECHO THIS IS NORMAL FUNCTION
GOTO BACK
```